# Ограничение длины заголовка новости на js в битрикс

Tags: php, битрикс

Прошу помощи или дать направление куда копать. Есть задача от заказчика, если в двух словах то заказчик хочет, когда редактор вводит название новости то ограничить по длине, при чем штатный функционал битрикса который не выведет больше чем символов чем можно, его не устраивает. Поэтому он хочет чтобы прямо при добавлении или редактировании новости всплывало либо окно, либо текст становился красным если введен превышенный лимит символов. Я пытался найти шаблон добавления или изменения элемента, но не могу найти. Я так понимаю мне надо найти этот элемент добавить туда код на js который посчитает символы и если превышен лимит то применить красный шрифт. Но где лежит шаблон я опять же не в курсе. Кто ни будь сталкивался с подобным?

Answer (score 0):

Один из вариантов, создать события (про события [тут](https://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/learning/course/index.php?COURSE_ID=43&LESSON_ID=3493&LESSON_PATH=3913.4619.3493)) , например [OnBeforeIBlockElementAdd](https://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/api_help/iblock/events/onbeforeiblockelementadd.php) и [OnBeforeIBlockElementUpdate](https://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/api_help/iblock/events/onbeforeiblockelementupdate.php)
При добавлении или изменении элемента в обработчик события попадёт массив с полями и свойствами (изменяемого / добавляемого) элемента. Остаётся проверить необходимое поле на количество символов и если превышает, то отменить добавление / обновление и вывести ошибку, типа "Длина заголовка превышает максимальную длину"